# understanding the sapui5 form layout

Tags: sapui5

I have picked a sample form xml view from demo kit and the link is :

[Link to xml view](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.layout.form.Form/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.Form_Column_twoGroups234/code/Change.fragment.xml)

and the Change Form is like:
[image]

Here I don't understand why Address form container has `5` form elements and for Contact form container has `4` and then next elements starting from a new column (`Mobile:`)

Can any one brief how to understand the above query also to understand how to add any no of rows below form container?

Also How can I set Labels and Input fields for the same form side by side?

Any Help for this beginner is Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Here I don't understand why Address form container has 5 form elements and for Contact form container has 4 and then next elements starting from a new column (Mobile:)

- As Address form container contains 5 form elements it is showing 5 form elements same applies to Contact form container which contains 4. You can add extra form elements to the Contact form container it will show 5 form elements.
- Next elements starting from a new column because the form container is
  responsive and it is written in different form containers(Address, Contact and Mobile).

How to add any no of rows below form container?

- Kindly elaborate your question? if you are talking about the data binding, then there is an aggregation `formContainers` which helps to achieve it.

Also How can I set Labels and Input fields for the same form side by side?

- Yes you can achieve it by giving empty `label` ie `<f:FormElement label="">` and using `<layoutData>` for alignment for the elements. But the layout and CSS is predefined you need to modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: But Contact form container has 7 form elements and it is divided in to two columns(how this is happening) 4 in as second column + 3 in as third column

Comment: As per the demo sample it contains only 2 `formContainers`. If you have your custom view, kindly share so that I can answer to your question

Comment: I guess her doubt is about no of labels and inputs alignment per column (for Contact they are 4 and for Address they are 5)